# There's something strange when I update gulp-uncss

Tags: node.js, phantomjs, gulp, io.js, uncss

When I update "gulp-uncss", there is a strange problem... It just stop when copying extracted folder... I tried many times... Each time is like this... I'm using "iojs-v1.0.4-x64", whether the cause of the problem is this?

Comment: Is there any output or are there any errors you can show us?

Comment: @Ding I can't attach images when describing my question... Here is the [output](http://g.hiphotos.baidu.com/image/pic/item/9345d688d43f8794b229caead11b0ef41ad53a1b.jpg).

Comment: @Ding Or you can check [here](http://image.baidu.com/detail/newindex?col=&tag=&pn=0&pid=16990595862&aid=406421571&user_id=663109398&setid=-1&sort=0&newsPn=&star=&fr=&from=2.baidu) for the output... There is no error, it just stop right there when copying extracted phantomjs...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may have run into this bug https://github.com/giakki/uncss/issues/142 - it's not a problem with UnCSS, it is with io.js.